# Trouble Getting HttpResponse data with AngularJS $http.post

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, http-post, out-of-memory, code-behind

I am try to return a custom object from VB.NET code behind to a AngularJS HTTP Post. Based on the user requests, this object could be very large. Very, very large. Whenever that happened, I got a OutOfMemoryException when trying to serialize it. Therefore, I am now using the JSON.NET package from Newtonsoft to serialze it using a StringWriter:

```
Using sw As New StringWriter()
    Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
        Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
        serializer.Serialize(writer, periodData)
        writer.Flush()
    End Using
End Using
```

While this works, when I then try to do `sw.ToString` I still get that OutOfMemoryException.

So, I trawled through the internet and I believe I can use a StreamWriter sent to a HttpResponse object and then flush the response to return it to the web client call. However, I cannot figure out how to do this.

Any help? Or if I am way off track, give me a better way to do this?

**Update 1**

Apparently, I cannot use HttpResponse in a Using statement because I get a "using operand must implement system.idisposable" error. So now I am having trouble creating an HttpResponse object in the WebMethod. Passing both TextWriter and HttpWriter as params for the constructor give me errors.

**Update 2**

Okay, so I am no longer getting an OutOfMemoryException when trying to serialize the object. However, I believe I am doing something wrong since my StreamWriter doesn't seem to be writing to the HttpResponse Object. This is my current code:

```
Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response()
response.ContentType = "application/json"
response.Clear()
response.BufferOutput = True

Using sw As New StreamWriter(response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
        Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
        serializer.Serialize(writer, periodData)
        writer.Flush()
    End Using
    sw.Flush()
End Using

response.Flush()
```

Then when I pause my JavaScript in the Chrome developer console, the response object is just an empty string. The javascript is just a basic Angular $http.post call:

```
$http.post('url.aspx/GetData', angular.toJson({
    param1: data1,
    param2: data2,
    param3: data3
})).then(function (response) {
    //Do stuff with response which is currently an empty string.
}
```

I don't believe my VB.NET code is correct. Help?

Comment: That you are running out of memory is not quite your problem since you have identified a solution *I can use a StreamWriter sent to a HttpResponse object and then flush the response to return it to the web client call*. Why don't you try that? If you run into problems, we can help, but we can't write your code for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question where you are, but it looks like you are having trouble constructing a StreamWriter to write into a HttpResponse.

You can get the response object from the HttpContext:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void YourServiceMethod()
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    // ... now go on
}
```

The response object has a property `OutputStream` that you can give to the constructor of `StreamWriter` (in a using statement), like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129963/1004651) to another question:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // ... now write your data
}
```

(Excuse me giving C# samples, that's what I am much more familiar with.)

Comment: How do I get the StreamWriter data into the HttpResponse object? Tried flushing the JsonWriter, StreamWriter, and HttpResponse object. None worked.

Comment: @MichaelWang The StreamWriter writes into the response's output stream, and you write into the StreamWriter - that's it, basically. --- You should really follow Verdolino's advice and put the essence of your current code into your question. It might be just a little detail that's wrong.